# Subclassed ForeignKey field not created for model

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I've been looking at Marty Alchin's Apress book 'ProDjango' and I've run into an issue with the last chapter (chapter 11). I'm a relative noob at Python and Django, and although I've tried searching around I can't put my finger on something similar through this and other forums. I have seen [Is Pro Django book still relevant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746344/is-pro-django-book-still-relevant) on this site but doesn't answer any specific questions.

The problem revolves around the trying to create a mechanism to track changes - a history of additions, changes and deletions. The first step is creating a user field on models you want to track. In the example project he has created a specialised ForeignKey field hard-coded to relate to Django's built-in 'User' model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CurrentUserField(models.ForeignKey):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CurrentUserField, self).__init__(User, null=True, **kwargs)
```

There is also a 'contrib_to_class() method later. The class is in a seperate models.py file from the models to which is to be applied.

The use, as I understand, is to add a new field referencing this new field class in your model:

e.g.

```
class SimpleModel(models.Model):
    a_user = CurrentUserField()
```

But the problem is that when I syncdb the field is nowhere to be found, a 'FieldError' is the usual result trying to access it.

There are many other elements in the book's solution that I haven't tried to copy here, but this is the first and fundamental part.

I'm guessng that changes in Django and/or Python itself are responsible here. Has anyone any pointers?

Thanks.

EDIT: Given the class below in registration.py which is the current_user folder. This is also where you find the models.py holding the CurrentUserField class. The InformationRequest models has:

```
user = CurrentUserField()
```

as its last field. All imports are present and appear correct.

```
class FieldRegistry(object):
    _registry = {}

    def add_field(self, model, field):
        reg = self.__class__._registry.setdefault(model, [])
        reg.append(field)

    def get_fields(self, model):
        return self.__class__._registry.get(model, [])

    def __contains__(self, model):
        return model in self.__class__._registry


In [1]: from current_user.registration import FieldRegistry

In [2]: from inforequest.models import InformationRequest

In [3]: registry = FieldRegistry()

In [4]: registry.add_field(InformationRequest, InformationRequest._meta.get_field('user'))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FieldDoesNotExist                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6fcbbdcae066> in <module>()
----> 1 registry.add_field(InformationRequest, InformationRequest._meta.get_field('user'))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.pyc in get_field(self, name, many_to_many)
    353             if f.name == name:
    354                 return f
--> 355         raise FieldDoesNotExist('%s has no field named %r' % (self.object_name, name))
    356 
    357     def get_field_by_name(self, name):

FieldDoesNotExist: InformationRequest has no field named 'user'
```

Trying to look at the admin generates "Unknown field(s)..."

Comment: Please show the exact error message you are getting including the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found an answer to my question: django-simple-history (https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), inasmuch it provides part of solution I was trying to achieve and apparently it was built on Marty Alchin's code in Pro Django.